# HTML5 <video> tag Chromecast/AirPlay events

Tags: javascript, html, video, google-cast, airplay

Given a vanilla HTML5 `<video>` tag, I can easily add event listeners for the usual suspects (`play`, `ended`, `timeupdate`, etc). Does anyone know if it's possible to register an event listener to know when the `<video>` is being sent to a Chromecast or AirPlay device?

The idea would be to be able to display supporting content on the "sending" device, instead of showing a blank space where the video would normally play.

Comment: Integrate with the Google Cast SDK for Chrome senders: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender

Comment: @LeonNicholls, per their documentation (and per experimentation) this SDK does *not* work for Android nor iOS: "neither Chrome for Android, nor Chrome for iOS supports Cast applications". However, the capability seems to exist natively on these devices.

Comment: The Cast SDK does work for the Chrome desktop browser. For the Chrome mobile browsers, Chrome has a native integration with the Cast SDK which is handled internally within the browser and not exposed to developers. This allows the mobile browser to Cast videos even if the page does use the Cast SDK.

Comment: @LeonNicholls thanks for your response. To clarify, this is to say that for mobile web applications (likely Javascript here), there is no such way to register an event listener for knowing when Chromecast is being used for a known `<video>` element?

Comment: No there is no way for the web page to know that the video is being casted by the mobile browser.

Comment: @LeonNicholls Do you have an updated link?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_setup